# Design multiple json object response for rest webservices using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I am new to Spring boot and rest webservices. I have a requirement to create rest webservices Crud operations and the response expected in `GET` request is something like:

```
[
 schema:
    {
     id:1
     tablename:xyz
     columnnane:abc
     nullable: false
   }
.....
data:
 {
    id:12
    name:abc
    age:25
    city:bangalore
} 
.... 
]
```

Here schema will send the list of entity(table) Metadata and data will send actual entity object back to a client.

What are the good design practices to achieve this?

Design classes for this kind of response in spring boot rest any services?

Please comment or share some useful links on this

Is there any design patterns to achieve this

I am planning to create `DTO` objects to map to entity class for this. Is this a good way to go about it?

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-crudrepository-example

Comment: This is nice link. But can you guide me on best practices to design response for schema and data as multiple json response objects

Comment: what is your mean about  'data as multiple json response objects' ! you can return your desired result from your controller.

Comment: I need to return Schema which will have list do column Metadata and data which will have list of business entity data. I created below class for this